# What context is available to ActiveRecord scopes in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

We had a model with the following `conditions` association in Rails 3:

```
has_many :practitioners, through: :roles, conditions: proc {
  if active?
    "deactivated_at is null"
  else
    ["deactivated_at is null or deactivated_at > ?", closed_at]
  end
}
```

I made a trivial update to Rails 4:

```
has_many :practitioners, -> {
  if active?
    "deactivated_at is null"
  else
    ["deactivated_at is null or deactivated_at > ?", closed_at]
  end
}, through: :roles
```

However, the `active?` and `closed_at` attributes of the model are not available inside the scope, so this doesn't work. How can I rewrite the scope to use those methods?

(Assume that if `active?` is true, `closed_at` is `nil`. What this says is, "only include practitioners who haven't been deactivated, or, if the model is closed, only include practitioners who hadn't been deactivated when the model was closed.")

Comment: I think with rails 4 you need to reference columns in a where clause. I don't think if blocks are possible